# How do I get source code from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, php

How can we get the source code of a webpage from a webpage in php and/or javascript?

Comment: Are you talking about the HTML of the webpage?

Comment: `file_get_contents($file_or_url);`

Comment: If from domain other than yours you must use server side language due to Same Origin policy. Otherwise (same domain) you can use AJAX.

Comment: thank you ,and can I do the same in js?

Comment: @user1365010 I'm not familiar with javascript, but if it's possible I would not do it on client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to:

- @PLB
- @Shadow Wizard
- [Getting the source code of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730865/getting-the-source-code-of-an-iframe)
- http://www.frihost.com/forums/vt-32602.html
- @Matt Coughlin.

First, you must know that you will never be able to get the source code of a page that is not on the same domain as your page in javascript. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

### In PHP, this is how you do it :

```
file_get_contents($theUrl);
```

### In javascript, there is three ways :

**Firstly, by XMLHttpRequest :** http://jsfiddle.net/635YY/1/

```
var url="../635YY",xmlhttp;//Remember, same domain
if("XMLHttpRequest" in window)xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
if("ActiveXObject" in window)xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
};
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

**Secondly, by iFrames :** http://jsfiddle.net/XYjuX/1/

```
var url="../XYjuX";//Remember, same domain
var iframe=document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.onload=function()
{
    alert(iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
}
iframe.src=url;
iframe.style.display="none";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

**Thirdly, by jQuery :** http://jsfiddle.net/edggD/2/

```
$.get('../edggD',function(data)//Remember, same domain
{
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Forget the Same-Origin policy in XHR! ;)

Comment: Not an answer to the question. The question was how to get the code for the *current* page, not how to query a new version of the file that the page was loaded from. Server files can change or even be dynamically generated.

Answer (score 10):

In Javascript without using unnecessary frameworks (in the example api.codetabs.com is a proxy to bypass Cross-Origin Resource Sharing):

```
fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=google.com').then((response) => response.text()).then((text) => console.log(text));
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question. The question was how to get the code for the *current* page, not how to query a new version of the file that the page was loaded from. Server files can change or even be dynamically generated.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax example using jQuery:

```
// Display the source code of a web page in a pre tag (escaping the HTML).
// Only works if the page is on the same domain.

$.get('page.html', function(data) {
    $('pre').text(data);
});
```

If you just want access to the source code, the data parameter in the above code contains the raw HTML source code.

Comment: Not an answer to the question. The question was how to get the code for the *current* page, not how to query a new version of the file that the page was loaded from. Server files can change or even be dynamically generated.

Answer (score 1):

Following [Google's guide on fetch()](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) and using the D.Snap answer, you would have something like this:

```
fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=URL_you_want_to_fetch')
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }

      // Examine the text in the response
      response.text().then(function(data) {
        // data contains all the plain html of the url you previously set, 
        // you can use it as you want, it is typeof string
        console.log(data)
      });
    }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  });
```

This way you are using a CORS Proxy, in this example it is [Codetabs CORS Proxy](https://codetabs.com/cors-proxy/cors-proxy.html).

A CORS Proxy allows you to fetch resources that are not in your same domain, thus avoiding the Same-Origin policies blocking your requests.
You can take a look at other CORS Proxys:

https://nordicapis.com/10-free-to-use-cors-proxies/

Comment: Not an answer to the question. The question was how to get the code for the *current* page, not how to query a new version of the file that the page was loaded from. Server files can change or even be dynamically generated.

Comment: @IsaacKing not really, read the question again: "How can we get the source code of *a webpage* from *a webpage in php and/or javascript*?"

This implies that he wants to get the code of a page from another page built either in PHP or JS, and that is what the answer shows, in this case in JS. By this questions, is it understood that the OP wants the HTML source code (press right click > View page source) and not the server-side code that generated the client-side view.