# Pulling already loaded JS into a local variable

Tags: javascript

The source of linked to .js is not available via the DOM currently.

```
var b = document.createElement("script");
b.type= "text/javascript";
b.src = "foo/source/ArcJ.js"  // dynamically load .js file
```

Can I just do

```
var c = b.src // probably not
```

I think this would just give me the path...I want the source...i.e. all the code in a string.

Is there a way to do this with out using ajax?  Shouldn't this be a simple DOM Pull...

```
document.getElementById(b.id).source_code
```

?

Comment: I guess the better way is to use XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Not sure how to do it, but b.src is probably only going to be the string "foo/source/ArcJ.js" and not the file content itself.

Comment: @MarkLinus I guess it's the only way...

Comment: Look my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932226/get-source-code-from-javascript/10933419#10933419

Comment: @pimvdb. `innerHTML` will be empty in this case...

Comment: Yes, never mind. Not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: @Hiro Protagonist: Yes, but a `<script src="..."></script>` is always empty, so my idea won't work anyway. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took from [How do I get source code from a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932226/get-source-code-from-javascript/10933419#10933419) (written by me)

There is three way in javascript :

**Firstly, by XMLHttpRequest :** http://jsfiddle.net/635YY/1/

```
var url="../635YY",xmlhttp;//Remember, same domain
if("XMLHttpRequest" in window)xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
if("ActiveXObject" in window)xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
};
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

**Secondly, by iFrames :** http://jsfiddle.net/XYjuX/1/

```
var url="../XYjuX";//Remember, same domain
var iframe=document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.onload=function()
{
    alert(iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
}
iframe.src=url;
iframe.style.display="none";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

**Thirdly, by jQuery :** http://jsfiddle.net/edggD/2/

```
$.get('../edggD',function(data)//Remember, same domain
{
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: If you feel this question is a duplicate, you may rather want to close the question as such.

Comment: It is loaded into the DOM already....is there some principle that would be broken by doing a direct DOM pull?

Answer (score 2):

.src is the url, so you just load the url from that using an ajax request...

```
$.get($("script[src*=jquery]").attr("src"),function(data){
    console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: You better add `script` tag to the selector, to boost it a little.

Comment: btw, if you script tag has code in it you can just call $("script").txt()