# Get html source code from a website and then get an element from the html file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get HTML code of a website and then get a certain element from that HTML file.

There are things that can get HTML code like ajax and jquery. I am using node and want it to be in total javascript. Also, I have no idea how to get a certain element from that.

I have done this in python but I need it in javascript. For simplicity. Let's take the website- https://example.com. This is the body of the HTML code of website.

```html
<body>
<div>
    #Some Stuff 
</div>
</body>
```

I want to get the div class lets take `<div>` to be `<div class="test">` to make it easier.

Finally, I want to get- the content of `<div class="test">`

Like this-

```html
<div class="test">
    #Some Stuff 
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you planning on attempting to fetch the html and parse it in-browser or on a Node.js server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Node.js there are two native fetching modules: `http` and `https`. If you're looking to scrape with a Node.js application, then you should probably use `https`, get the page's html, parse it with an html parser, I'd recommend `cheerio`. Here's an example:

```
// native Node.js module
const https = require('https')
// don't forget to `npm install cheerio` to get the parser!
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

// custom fetch for Node.js
const fetch = (method, url, payload=undefined) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get(
        url,
        res => {
            const dataBuffers = []
            res.on('data', data => dataBuffers.push(data.toString('utf8')))
            res.on('end', () => resolve(dataBuffers.join('')))
        }
    ).on('error', reject)
})

const scrapeHtml = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  fetch('GET', url)
  .then(html => {
    const cheerioPage = cheerio.load(html)
    // cheerioPage is now a loaded html parser with a similar interface to jQuery
    // FOR EXAMPLE, to find a table with the id productData, you would do this:
    const productTable = cheerioPage('table .productData')

    // then you would need to reload the element into cheerio again to
    // perform more jQuery like searches on it:
    const cheerioProductTable = cheerio.load(productTable)
    const productRows = cheerioProductTable('tr')

    // now we have a reference to every row in the table, the object
    // returned from a cheerio search is array-like, but native JS functions
    // such as .map don't work on it, so we need to do a manually calibrated loop:
    let i = 0
    let cheerioProdRow, prodRowText
    const productsTextData = []
    while(i < productRows.length) {
      cheerioProdRow = cheerio.load(productRows[i])
      prodRowText = cheerioProdRow.text().trim()
      productsTextData.push(prodRowText)
      i++
    }
    resolve(productsTextData)
  })
  .catch(reject)
})

scrapeHtml(/*URL TO SCRAPE HERE*/)
.then(data => {
  // expect the data returned to be an array of text from each 
  // row in the table from the html we loaded. Now we can do whatever
  // else you want with the scraped data. 
  console.log('data: ', data)
})
.catch(err => console.log('err: ', err)
```

Happy scraping!

Comment: Thank you so Much It worked totally fine as it was simple to adjust it to my requirements.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

See the working example below. You can do more stuff in the for loop if necessary. 
In general you can access the Html-Content of most Objects via `.innerHTML`.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
   console.log(divs[i].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    #Some Stuff 
</div>
```

When you want to get the SourceCode of a Site on the same Domain you can use this [How do I get source code from a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932226/how-do-i-get-source-code-from-a-webpage) and combine it with my given solution for your second problem.

Comment: The question mentioned using Node.js, not in-browser JavaScript. There is no reference to document in that case. See my answer for appropriate way of fetching and parsing html in Node.

Answer (score 1):

You will never be able to get the source code of a page that is not on the same domain as your page in javascript. 
Please take a look :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

If the domain is the same you can get it by iFrames:

```
var url=".../xxxx"; // same domain !
var iframe=document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.onload=function()
{
var result= iframe.contentWindow.document.body.querySelector('.test').innerHTML);
alert(result);
}
iframe.src=url;
iframe.style.display="none";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

var result access the iframe and select the element that have class named "test" and get its inner html in your case the result will be :

```
    #Some Stuff
```